# How to find the value of the given limit with summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

It was asked to find the value of the following limit: $$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{96}{n^4}\left[1\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)+2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k\right)+3\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} k\right)+\cdots+n \cdot 1\right]
$$
Here's my try on it:

Let the general $m^{th}$ term of the series be
$$\begin{align}t_m &= m \left( \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n-m+1}k \right)\\
                   &= m\ .\dfrac{(n-m+1)(n-m+2)}{2}
\end{align}$$
So,
$$  \begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^n t_m &=\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m(n-m+1)(n-m+2)}{2} \\
                 &=\sum_{s=0}^{n-1} \frac{(s+1)(n-s)(n-s+1)}{2} \end{align}
$$
From here I have no clue how to proceed further with this series.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Well it is given as hint to find the highest degree term in the summation, does this help us in anyway to proceed further with that series?

Comment: Apply the formula for $\sum_{k=1}^m k$ for $m=n,n-1,\cdots, 1$. Then you will have a sum of terms. Write this in an convenient form.

Comment: $$\sum_{s=0}^{n-1} \frac{(s+1)(n-s)(n-s+1)}{2}\overset{k=n-s}{=}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-k+1)k(k+1)}{2}$$
$$=\frac{n}{2}\sum_{k=1}^nk(k+1)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^nk(k^2-1)=\Big(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\Big)\sum_{k=1}^nk\,+\frac{n}{2}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^nk^3$$
All the sums are well-known; and only you need the biggest terms ($\sim n^4$) of them. For example, $\displaystyle\frac{n}{2}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n}{2}(n^3/3+An^2+Bn+C)\to\frac{n^4}{6}$, etc.

Comment: These sums can be calculated. Sum of polynomial $p(k)$ from 1 to $n$ is polynomial of $n$ of increased degree. Other method: When $n$ is approaching infinity one can use variable $\frac{k}{n}=y$, $\frac{m}{n}=x$ and transform sums to integrals. Then result is $96\int_0^1 x \left(\int_0^{1-x} y\, dy\right)\, dx$.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you write $\displaystyle \frac{k}{n}=y$ and $\displaystyle \frac{m}{n}=x$, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If we look at the inside sum we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1}i
$$
Now we have that the inside sum is the triangle numbers namely we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1}i=\frac{(n-k+1)(n-k+2)}{2}
$$
Thus, we have that the sum becomes
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k(n-k+1)(n-k+2)}{2}
$$
Now if we factor everything out and gather things in terms of $k$ we get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^nk^3-(2n+3)k^2+(n^2+3n+2)k
$$
Then if we break up the sums we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^nk^3
-\frac{2n+3}{2}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^nk
$$
Now if we use the well-known formulas
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2
$$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$
and the formula for the triangle numbers above, we then see that the sum becomes
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2-\frac{2n+3}{2}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
Now we are really only interested in the $n^4$ term as the lower order terms will be killed when we take the limit.

If we see from the first term we will get a factor of $\frac{n^4}{8}+O(n^3)$, the second factor, we will get a factor of $-\frac{n^4}{3}+O(n^3)$, and the last term will give us a $\frac{n^4}{4}+O(n^3)$

Thus, we have the above is
$$
\frac{1}{24}n^4+O(n^3)
$$
Thus, when we consider
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{96}{n^4}\cdot\text{sum}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{96}{n^4}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{24}n^4+O(n^3)\right)=4
$$

Comment: How can a sum of positive thing be negative?

Comment: You are correct, I had made an error and forget the $n^2$ term in front of the $k$ term when I broke up the sum, this gives and extra $\frac{n^4}{4}$ which makes the result positive. The typos have been fixed and I've edited my solution.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left[j\sum_{k=1}^{n-j+1} k\right]$. Write out $A_{n-1}$ and notice that $A_n-A_{n-1}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}k$ (write out terms by terms if necessary). Since $n^4$ is strictly monotone and divergent sequence, by [Stolz–Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{A_n}{n^4}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{A_n-A_{n-1}}{n^4-(n-1)^4}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}k}{4n^3-6n^2+4n-1}.
$$
Letting $B_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}k$ and applying Stolz–Cesàro similarly again

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{B_n}{4n^3-6n^2+4n-1}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k}{12n^2-24n+14}.
$$
And just for consistency $C_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$ and for the last time

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{C_n}{12n^2-24n+14}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{24n-36}=\frac{1}{24}.
$$
Hence the answer is $\frac{96}{24}=4$.

Answer (score 1):

The given limit can be written as
$$\begin{align}&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{96}{n^4}\sum_{m=1}^nm\sum_{k=1}^{n-m+1}k
\\\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{96}{n^4}\sum_{m=1}^{n}m\cdot\frac{(n-m+1)(n-m+2)}{2}
\\\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{48}{n}\sum^{n}_{m=1}\frac mn\bigg(1-\frac mn+\frac 1n\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac mn+\frac 2n\bigg)
\\\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{48}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac mn\bigg(\bigg(1-\frac mn\bigg)^2+\frac 3n\bigg(1-\frac mn\bigg)+\frac{2}{n^2}\bigg)
\\\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{48}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac mn\bigg(1-\frac mn\bigg)^2
\\&\qquad +\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{48}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac mn\bigg(\frac 3n\bigg(1-\frac mn\bigg)+\frac{2}{n^2}\bigg)
\\\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{48}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac mn\bigg(1-\frac mn\bigg)^2
\\&\qquad +\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{48}{n^4}\sum_{m=1}^{n}(3mn-3m^2+2m)\tag1\end{align}$$

The second term is equal to $0$, so we get
$$\begin{align}(1)&=48\int_0^1x(1-x)^2dx
\\\\&=48\int_0^1(x-2x^2+x^3)dx
\\\\&=48\bigg(\frac 12-\frac 23+\frac 14\bigg)
\\\\&=\color{red}4\end{align}$$

---

**Added** :

Ivan Kaznacheyeu's comment is helpful.

First of all, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{96}{n^4}\sum_{m=1}^{n}m\sum_{k=1}^{n-m+1}k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{96}{n^4}\sum_{m=1}^{n}m\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n-m}}k\tag1$$
because
$$\begin{align}&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{96}{n^4}\sum_{m=1}^{n}m\sum_{k=1}^{n-m+1}k
\\\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{96}{n^4}\sum_{m=1}^{n}m\bigg(n-m+1+\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n-m}}k\bigg)
\\\\&=\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{96}{n^4}\sum_{m=1}^{n}m(n-m+1)}_{=0}
\\&\qquad +\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{96}{n^4}\sum_{m=1}^{n}m\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n-m}}k\end{align}$$

Now, $(1)$ can be written as
$$(1)=96\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac mn\underbrace{\bigg(\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-m}\frac kn\bigg)}_{S}\tag2$$

Here, $S$ is as follows :

[image]

Therefore, we finally get
$$\begin{align}(2)&=96\int_{0}^{1}x\bigg(\int_{0}^{1-x}y\ dy\bigg)dx
\\\\&=96\int_0^1\frac{x(1-x)^2}{2}dx
\\\\&=4\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks mathlove. Can you please explain me How Even kaznacheyeu write the limit in double integral form by substituting $\displaystyle \frac{k}{n}=y,\frac{m}{n}$ and that limit convert into $\displaystyle 96\int^1_0 x(\int^{1-x}_0ydy)dx$.

Comment: @jacky : I added some explanations.